# Java fire bullet using iterator

Tags: java, iterator

I don't know if I get it right but i have something like:

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
Iterator itr;
```

if I press SPACE `fire` become true.

```
if (fire) {
   Bullet bullet = new Bullet(ship.getX(), ship.getY(), true);
   al.add(bullet);
   itr = al.iterator();
   fire = false;
}
while(itr.hasNext()) {
//here i want my Bullet class funcion move();
// something liek itr.move();

}
```

It's probably all wrong. But could you give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

With an ArrayList all you need for iteration is a for loop.  Incidentally, you didn't specify what type the ArrayList contains.  It should be ArrayList<Bullet> al = new ArrayList<Bullet>();

For iteration try:

```
for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++)
{
  ....
}
```

Type safety is important!  If you use type safe declarations then you don't need to cast returned values.

Answer (score 0):

To get value from iterator you should use `next()` method. This method returns value pointed by iterator and moves iterator to the next element in container.

```
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    Bullet bullet = (Bullet) itr.next();
    bullet.move();
}
```

Since Java  1.5 you can iterate over the collection in even more elegant way (which does same as above but you don't have to worry about an iterator):

```
for(Bullet bullet : al) { // Assuming you use generic ArrayList<Bullet>
    bullet.move();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. it works. Can I somehow destroy bullet that flies off the window? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically Your first approach was best for this kind of situation, calling `delete` on iterator allows You to remove bullet from collection in the same pass as moving.

```
final ArrayList test = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("test", "Foo", "Bar"));

final Iterator iterator = test.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    final String next = iterator.next();
//Some action on Your bullet
    System.out.println(next);
//check if you want to remove it
    if ("Bar".equals(next)) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
    System.out.println(test);
}
```